# What technology is the Asana Iphone app based on?

Tags: asana

I have been using the Asana App for Iphone and find it works very smooth and efficiently. I was wondering if it was developed using a specific framework or if it is just native code...  I googled for info but could not find any information.

Answer (score 0):

Its strange that you didn't find the answers by googling.

http://www.quora.com/Asana/Why-is-it-taking-months-for-Asana-to-deliver-a-native-mobile-app-with-offline-support

http://www.quora.com/Asana/What-technologies-is-Asana-built-with

http://www.quora.com/Web-Architecture/What-architecture-does-Asana-use

http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-technologies-that-are-used-to-build-real-time-collaborative-systems-such-as-Asana-and-Trello

http://www.quora.com/Web-Application-Frameworks/What-are-the-differences-between-Meteor-and-Luna

http://www.quora.com/Asana/What-is-the-technology-stack-of-Asana

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I was asking about the mobile version of the asana app. :)

Comment: Updated the link in answer. It has been HTML5 wrapper version not native. But its likely they have built native by now. Not sure though.